# Adjacent Gray code

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, permutations

Gray code is permutation of $\{0,1,2,\dots,2^n-1\}$ such that each of consecutive number is differs only one bit in binary representation.

Example for $n = 3$

$000\\
001\\
011\\
010\\
110\\
111\\
101\\
100$

Let $s_k$ is bit position of transition $k$ to $k+1$. 
In example for $n=3$ above are $s_1=3,s_2=2,s_3=3,s_4=1$ and so on

I define adjacent gray code is each consecutive number is differs in adjacent bit. It is, if $s_k=j$ than $s_{k+1}$ is $j-1$ or $j+1$

Example for $n=4$

$0000\\
0001\\
0011\\
0111\\
0101\\
0100\\
0110\\
0010\\
1010\\
1110\\
1100\\
1101\\
1111\\
1011\\
1001\\
1000$

Can anyone design a good algorithm to look for adjacent gray code for $n$ large enough? Maybe it's acceptable for $n\leq10$

Comment: Have you tried constructing such a code explicitly?

Comment: WLOG let each Gray code start at all zeroes. Then, for $n = 6$ there does not exist an adjacent Gray code in which the second number is $000001$ or $000010$. Only $000100$ works (and by symmetry $001000$). There does not exist an adjacent Gray code for $n = 7$ at all.

Comment: @orlp how to prove for n=6, only 000100 works?

Comment: @LLawliet I used a brute force algorithm.

Comment: @orlp what kind of BF algo are you using? My BF is just try all permutation and it took very long hours for n = 5

Comment: Backtracking search: https://gist.github.com/orlp/c5a39c226be17a1b5fe3f30a06fd5ba3.